# Docker compose - Start/Stop services dynamically

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a docker-compose structure that sort of mimics AWS Lambda, I have my main `API`, an `AWS Lambda Service emulator`, and several `Lambda Function` images.

```yaml
services:
  api:
    #...
  lambda_server:
    #...
  lambda_f_1:
    #...
  lambda_f_2:
    #...
  lambda_f_3:
    #...
  lambda_f_4:
    #...
```

The problem with the above is that each `lambda_f_n` is quite heavy, I can't have them all running at once.

The idea is that `api` talks to `lambda_server`, which spins up a `lambda_f_x`, which then returns an output back to `lambda_server` and stops executing. So each `lambda_f_x` is `run` dynamically and has an ephemeral lifecycle

My current solution actually just doesn't have any `lambda_f_x` in the compose definition, and they are `run` by `lambda_server` using `Docker HTTP API`, that works with one very annoying caveat: When you `compose down`, they keep running, making local development hell

Is there a way I can Start/Stop services inside a `docker compose` dynamically? Or dynamically add containers to a `docker compose` group so that they all `stop` together?

Comment: It's possible, but not without giving the orchestration container unrestricted root-level access to the entire host system.  You'll have some difficulty running Compose _per se_ in this setup, but if you have a Docker SDK then you can dynamically create containers (and potentially leak containers, and potentially run containers as root that mount the host filesystem).

Comment: @DavidMaze From what you describe it sounds like what I'm already doing at the "My current solution..." part of the question. The issue is that the dynamically created containers are not part of the compose "group" and don't get removed along with them

Answer (score 0):

docker compose is just a simple language to run several predefined containers together, but not a fully featured container orchestration tool.
You may want to check out docker swarm or Kubernetes that are capable of starting/stopping containers dynamically, or in your current setup just add a shutdown hook to drop all related containers on shutdown.